# How to find out what slows down a freshly installed OS?

Tags: performance

I have two Fairphone 2 devices here, one owned by me, one by my mother. She got hers in September 2017, I in January 2019. Mine has a few slightly upgraded pieces, like a better camera and battery, but is otherwise identical. I first installed Fairphone Open on mine and it ran smoothly. Then I installed it on my mother's phone, which was already slow with the old system.
When going through the initial setup, it was so slow that some screens stayed white for ~30 seconds and it didn't get any faster later.

So the usual performance troubleshooting steps like "stop background apps", "factory reset", etc. don't apply here. It's also not the operating system's fault, because I used the same on a nearly identical device. For that reason, I suspect a hardware problem, caused by higher than usual wear (she doesn't handle her devices too carefully). But how do I check that? Are there special tools that I can use to detect for example lower than usual battery voltage or check the CPU and RAM for faults or anything like that, which could help in narrowing down the cause or the performance issues?

Comment: Did you perform a "clean install" (i.e. wiped cache and data) when installing FO on your mother's device? If not, that might be the reason (internal structures might have changed with the new system, and so it might have problems accessing things that have the "wrong" structure).

Comment: Execute a benchmark for CPU and GPU - and keep on eye on the temperatures. May be the heat spreader lost contact because of the "higher than usual wear"?

Comment: @Izzy I don't know the internals, I used the official Fairphone Open installation script for Linux.

Comment: @Robert Can you recommend a benchmark app?

Comment: Found one, Antutu, that name is familiar.

Comment: To put it in other words: you wrote "the usual performance troubleshooting steps like "stop background apps", "factory reset", etc. don't apply here" – but they do, at least factory reset. Because after a "dirty flash" (i.e. without wiping cache and data) of a different ROM there might be issues, a "clean flash" (i.e. with wipe of cache and data) is recommended. Wiping cache and data is exactly what a [tag:factory-reset] does.

Comment: So you mean a factory reset from the settings could help? Or should I also clear something else from TWRP?

Comment: The Antutu benchmark only gave me "CPU performance", otherwise nothing that looked useful. The CPU performance seemed not too much different. A factory reset seems like it could have improved performance, but I haven't tested that too much yet.

Comment: There's some people who've had show fairphones's. I feel its notable to mention only one where there was a 2-3 second delay and re-mounting the screen module solved it https://forum.fairphone.com/t/touchscreen-response-is-slow-very-very-slow/18172 so it kind of shows a possible problem with these devices where the hardware may not get connected correctly causing extra problems. Though its not the only thing that could cause slowdown. I do also feel though its likely hardware related since it does it on setup. Probably won't do any good to check cpu/gpu problem as these appear to be non-replace

Comment: Interesting find. But it's not the touchscreen, I see the touch dots from the developer settings instantly most of the time, it's just the apps reacting to it that is slow.